# server variable document root is not playing nice with file_exists when virtual folder is involved

Tags: php, file-exists, document-root, server-variables, virtual-path

I've got a virtual folder on IIS. 
When I do a server document root, I'm not getting `file_exists` find the files. But interestingly, if I use include (or require directives for that matter) same files being found.

example

```
$full_path = $_server['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/file.txt";
include($full_path); // works fine. 
if file_exists($full_path) : // returns false!
```

Again, this is only when I have a virtual folder involved.

I guess I have to use a different server variable which is not effected by whether there is a virtual folder or not.

eventually, I'd like the following to work

`/wwwroot/file.txt` should be found with this

`file_exists($_server['?'] . "/file.txt")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a config file and define baseroot and publicroot.

```
<?php
// myconfig.php -- stored in the public root
$direx = explode("/", getcwd());
DEFINE ('BASEROOT', '/'.$direx[1].'/'.$direx[2].'/'); // host/mysite/
DEFINE ('PUBLICROOT', '/'.$direx[1].'/'.$direx[2].'/'.$direx[3].'/'); // host/mysite/public_html/
?>

<?php
require_once('myconfig.php'); // called on every page

IF (File_Exists(PUBLICROOT.'some_folder/file.txt')) { /* do something */ }

include_once(PUBLICROOT.'some_folder/file.txt');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how IIS virtual folders behave, but you get the current scripts full file path from a global constant `__FILE__`, see at http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php.

If you know the relative path from your script, use something like this:

```
$filepath = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../file.txt";
```

Not sure if this solves your problem though.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is not trying to find out what the full path of the file I'm in. I should be able to pass a virtual root ( the way I see it on the browser ), and PHP should give me the true file path to that virtual path appears on the browser. Example: site.com/folderX/fileX.txt should be able to be found with doc_root . "/folderX/fileX.txt"